# Android login form using Post

Tags: android, post, http-post

I am trying to create a post request to the following api:

[consumer.api.mobdev.machies.com](http://consumer.api.mobdev.machies.com)

In order to do this, I have written the following code:

```
    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://consumer.api.mobdev.machies.com/v3/logins");

    try {
        // Add user name and password
     EditText uname = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.username);
     String username = uname.getText().toString();

     EditText pword = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.password);
     String password = pword.getText().toString();

        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(3);
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("grant_type","password"));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", username));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));
        httpPost.setHeader("Host","http://consumer.api.mobdev.machies.com");
        httpPost.setHeader("Content-Type","application/xml");
        httpPost.setHeader("Accept-Language","en-US");
                    httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

        // Execute HTTP Post Request
        Log.w("Post", "Execute HTTP Post Request");
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpPost);

        String str = inputStreamToString(response.getEntity().getContent()).toString();
```

str refers to the response that I get. Upon printing it in logcats, I got the following a response saying invalid hostname. Is there something wrong with the hostname that I've put in my code? Please help as I am new to using rest style apis

Comment: it means your application url is some wat wrong.. check the url you have passed in http post method.

Comment: You need to perform your HTTP request on a separate thread. Read this: http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2012/06/app-force-close-honeycomb-ics.html

Comment: The app is not crashing. It the response I get from the server says invalid host name. As for putting the code in a worker thread. i am aware of this, I just did it this way to see if it actually works and will add the threading part when thats the case. If you look at the link you provided, "Applications targeting earlier SDK versions are allowed to do networking on their main event loop threads, but it’s heavily discouraged." So it should work but just be slow.

Comment: So its not the "Host" header?

Comment: I tried to hit it in browser.its saying server not found

Comment: I did this because it was meant to be an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

may be use HttpClient here its may helps you

```
          HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(strUrl);
    if (mHeader != null) {
        for (Header header : mHeader) {
            httpPost.addHeader(header);
        }
    }
    try {
        MultipartEntity entity = new MultipartEntity(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
        if (nameValuePair != null) {
            ContentBody cb;
            for(NameValuePair value: nameValuePair){
                cb =  new StringBody(value.getValue(),"", null);
                entity.addPart(value.getName(), cb);
            }
        }
        if(filepath != null && filepath.length() > 0){
            File f = new File(filepath);
            entity.addPart("uploadedfile", new FileBody(f));
        }
        httpPost.setEntity(entity);

        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        response = EntityUtils.toString(httpResponse.getEntity());
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        //Display();


    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        //Display();            
    }

    if (mIsProgress)
        progress.dismiss();
    return response;
}
```